# Insert result of a parallellized select query into a table, in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, performance, parallelism, query-performance

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html,

> "Even when it is in general possible for parallel query plans to be
>   generated, the planner will not generate them for a given query if any
>   of the following are true:
>       The query writes any data or locks any database rows. If a query contains a data-modifying operation either at the top level or within
>   a CTE, no parallel plans for that query will be generated. This is a
>   limitation of the current implementation which could be lifted in a
>   future release."

Indeed, when I try to insert result of a parallel SELECT query into a table (either by SELECT.. INTO either by WITH..SELECT..INTO, the query is not executed as parallel query.

My question is: Is there any way to trick the Postgresql so that a SELECT query is executed as parallel query and then its result inserted into a table?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47092380/330315 (and here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47057891/330315)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only even worth trying is to use [PostgreSQL FDW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) which may or may not work. Your use case would also have to be super-niche for that to pay off, like a complex GIS aggregation query.

You can see this restriction is still very much [noted in the code,](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/32470825d36d99a81347ee36c181d609c952c061/src/backend/access/transam/README.parallel)

> The most significant restriction imposed by parallel mode is that all operations must be strictly read-only; we allow no writes to the database and no DDL.  We might try to relax these restrictions in the future.

And, [again here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c6764eb3aea63f3f95582bd660785e2b0d4439f9/src/backend/executor/execMain.c#L169)

```
 * Don't allow writes in parallel mode.  Supporting UPDATE and DELETE
 * would require (a) storing the combocid hash in shared memory, rather
 * than synchronizing it just once at the start of parallelism, and (b) an
 * alternative to heap_update()'s reliance on xmax for mutual exclusion.
 * INSERT may have no such troubles, but we forbid it to simplify the
 * checks.
```

I think it's being stopped by a call to `ExecCheckXactReadOnly` here in [`ExecCheckXactReadOnly`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c6764eb3aea63f3f95582bd660785e2b0d4439f9/src/backend/executor/execMain.c#L768)

```
if (plannedstmt->commandType != CMD_SELECT || plannedstmt->hasModifyingCTE)
    PreventCommandIfParallelMode(CreateCommandTag((Node *) plannedstmt));
```

Shy of that Maybe in PostgreSQL 11, or 12?

Answer (score 0):

Parallelism can be used read part of query. For example,

```
insert into t1 select * from parallel_exec();
```

Now if there is some statement in parallel_exec() function, that can
use parallelism, such as a select statement then you can do this:

Example function definition which can use parallelism:

```
create or replace function parallel_exec() returns integer
as $$
begin
        Perform * from t1 where c1 >= 10 and c1 < 11;
return 1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```